# c++: How to pass a raw string to a function like evaluate( "2+2\0+2" )?

Tags: c++, string, templates, c++11, null

EDIT:: `std::string infix="2+2\0+2";` how to pass it to the function `evaluate(std::string s){cout << s}`?  => 2+2+2 ?

EDIT2:: `\0` is a `NULL` character; my function to check grammar reads every character from string and if it is different than numeric or operator it throws an exception. I would like to read null character and throws an exception, but `evaluate("2+2\0+2")` returns `4`.

---

I am writing a simple calculator in c++11 with tests, supporting an infix notation.

And I have a function `int evaluate( const std::string & infix )` which calculates the result from my string (i.e. `evaluate( "((-3+--4*-(-19+5)))" )` returns `53`). And everything works just fine until...

When I create some tests I can write `ASSERT_EQ(6, evaluate("2+2+2"))`. But when I write `ASSERT_EQ(6, evaluate("2+2\0+2")` everything goes wrong (this should throw an `exception` but it returns `4`).

So how to pass an array of characters into a function, not knowing it size and having null characters inside of it? When `const char cstr[] = "2+\0+2"; evaluate(cstr);` does not send a full array :(

Comment: You can't have null byte in string literal. C++ does not know length of an array (`char[]`) so it supposes it ends with `\0`.

Comment: Exactly that is the problem! So how to protect yourself when you have a public function like `evaluate( std::string or any other const*char )` and someone want to write a test like `ASSERT_..(evaluate( "\0" ))` ??

Comment: @Zereges that's wrong. You can very well have null bytes in string literals, and the size of an array is part of its type. `std::string` just doesn't have a template constructor to directly take in the array, so a bit of care must be taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not on the function's side, but on the caller's. To construct a `std::string` from a string literal containing null bytes, you need to use one of the overloads that takes in information about the size of the string.

One such overload ([number 4 here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)) takes in the `char` pointer, and the size. Since string literals are `char` arrays, you can retrieve their size with a function template :

```
template <std::size_t N>
std::string make_string(char const (&lit)[N]) {
    return {lit, N};
}
```

... and use it thusly :

```
ASSERT_EQ(6, evaluate(make_string("2+2\0+2")));
```

You can also use the same principle to handle string literals directly by overloading your function :

```
template <std::size_t N>
auto evaluate(char const (&lit)[N]) {
    return evaluate({lit, N});
}
```

Comment: Yes! And now how to overload constructor to have it by default without using preprocessor? string("2+2) calls string("2+2",3)? Is it possible?

Comment: @MrAker turns out macros aren't even needed. I wonder why I didn't see that faster.

Comment: still, i can not write evaluate("2+2\0+2"), I have to write evalutate(function("")) :<

Answer (score 0):

> When const char cstr[] = "2+/0+2"; evaluate(cstr); does not send a full array :(

You can use use constructor of [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) which accepts iterator range, example:

```
// Using macro
#define ARR_TO_STR(a) std::string(std::cbegin(a), std::cend(a))

// And template function
template <typename T, size_t N>
std::string ArrToStr( T (&t)[N] ) {
    return std::string(std::cbegin(t), std::cend(t));
}

int main()
{
   ASSERT_EQ(6, evaluate(ArrToStr("2+\0+2")))
}
```

Comment: Yes, but during tests I do not create any variables, I just have a function to which I can send a string or any other char array. :((((((((((((((

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are not trying to test "2 plus 2 null_byte plus 2", but rather you are trying to test "2 plus 2 divided by zero plus 2".

If so, remember that in C++ string literals you need to type in a double backslash (because backslash is used as an escape character for many untypable characters).

Try

```
ASSERT_EQ(6, evaluate("2+2\\0+2"))
```

or, because you are using C++11

```
ASSERT_EQ(6, evaluate(R"2+2\0+2"))
```

to use "raw" string literals

Comment: Yes! But when someone who tests it is not nice and want to show to me that my programm is BAD(!), and will not put any "R" before his or her string, how to protect myself from such people and people's behaviour?

Comment: You can't protect yourself from people writing tests in C++, if they don't know how to write C++! If they don't make this mistake, they make some other. If your test code is to be written by non-developers, have them write something like "2+2+2=6" and "2+2\0+2=error" in a text file, and have a test tool that runs all the test in the file. But do not let them near your C++ compiler!

Comment: @MrAker The `divide` sign is `/` (have a look at your numeric keypad). Use it instead of `\\` and all your problems will go away.

Comment: @ZDF, well spotted. +1

Comment: XD @ZDF I want to send a null character inside a string, not a division characte XXXXXDDDDD

Comment: @MrAker You already did and you are not satisfied with the result. A null character means _"my string ends here"_. `null character` is not the same with `zero character`. Null is `'\\0'` or `0x00`. Zero is `'0'` or `0x31`.

Comment: @MrAker Erratum `0x30`, not `0x31`.

Comment: Fine! So how to send an array of chars to the function, where I do not know the length of an array (`const char cstr[]="2+2\0+2`, `evaluate(cstr)`) and read my array till the end (sizeof(cstr)==8, because it is a pointer)?

Comment: I got you wrong! Actually I am trying to test "2 plus 2 null_byte plus 2", not (2+2/0+2) ! SORRY!!!!!!